# Reduce dimensions of data set MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-science, dimensionality-reduction

I have a dataset of points in 4-dimensional space (matrix of size(n,4)) and would like to map it into 2-dimensional space without losing information on the relative euclidean distance between points. I've been trying to use MATLAB's cmdscale (or mdscale) without success. Are these the right approaches?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Matrix of size (n,4) is 2 dimensions- one of length N and one of length 4. Can you clarify your question, and/or provide some examples?

Comment: Maybe you should use the Johnson-Lindenstrauss transform

Comment: @Adiel sorry I should have explained myself better. I have a matrix of n observations with 4 features each. So each row in my (nx4) matrix corresponds to a point in 4-dimensional space and each column corresponds to the respective x1,x2,x3 and x4 coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that you can embed points from 4 dimensional euclidean space in 2-dimensional space while keeping the relative distances the same. Once n > 3, it is generically impossible. cmdscale embeds the points in the smallest dimensional space (p) possible which will generically be 4 in your case.